# Find the PDFs of X+Y

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X$, $Y$ have joint PDF,

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }~0 \le y \le 1,~2y\le x \le 2
\\[1ex]
0 &\text{if elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Find the PDF of $X + Y$.

Hi, I am stuck on this problem.

so I think I have to divide $X+Y$ into several intervals and then... what should I do?

Comment: The geometrical way is to check that (X,Y) is uniform on the triangle with vertices (0,0), (2,0), (2,1) hence, intersecting this triangle with lines of slope -1, one sees that the PDF of Z=X+Y is linear on (0,2) and on (2,3), zero at 0 and 3, and continuous at 2. Since every PDF integrates to 1, this yields the PDF z/2 for 0<z<2 and 3-z for 2<z<3.

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that the density function of the sum is the convolution: $$f_{X+Y}(z) = \int_\Bbb R f_{X,Y}(x, z-x)\operatorname d x$$

And by substituting into the joint density you have: $$\begin{align}f_{X,Y}(z,z-x) ~=~ &\begin{cases} 1 & : 0\leq z-x\leq 1~, 2(z-x)\leq x\leq 2\\[1ex] 0 & :\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\\[2ex] ~=~ &\begin{cases} 1 & : \max(z-1,2z/3)\leq x\leq \min(z,2)~, 0\leq z\leq 3\\[1ex] 0 & :\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from here?